# How to make my script install the needed requirements at the first time it runs in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have designed a code that requires a number of packages to run. as I run it on a different computer it will need to install the packages so I did it manually but as it spreads I will need to do so automatically at the first time it runs.

I have added lines of pip install the packages one by one in the beginning of code.
I am asking if there a cleaner way to do so.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. create a requirements.txt file at the project root location.
   keep package details in the file like `pandas==1.3.0`.

   all packages will be installed with a one simple command
   `pip install -r requirements.txt`
2. check for the missing packages and install it.

```
packages = [
    "pandas==1.3.0",
    "requests==0.1.1"
]

for package in required_packages:
    try:
        importlib.import_module(package.split("==")[0])
    except ImportError:
        print(f"Installing {package}...")
        subprocess.call(["pip", "install", package])
```

This code will check and import packages, if not present will install packages using `pip`.